# rails 3 sql selection current_user.comments (where @comment.article_id = @article.id)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I googled my question but it seems like I don't know what's it called that I'm looking for.
What I basically want is a selection of a current_user's or other user's comments. They should be displayed below an article as a possible feature, but what's important is that only the user's comments, which belong to the current article shall be displayed. Right now, when I call current_user.comments, all the user's comments are shown, but I only want those where the comment's article_id matches the current article.
How are these things done in Rails?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: current_user.comments.all should give comments belongs to current user. Can you post SQL generated by current_user.comments.all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
current_user.comments.where(:article_id => params[:article_id])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Needed to edit it slightly to `current_user.comments.where(:article_id => params[:id])`